# How to Monitor pipeline a from pipeline b in azure datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have 2 pipelines, A and B.

I want to monitor the current status of A from B. If A is currently running then do not run B, but if A is already completed or did not run then start pipeline B.

This should be done in Azure Data Factory.

How can I approach this?

Comment: According to your logic flow, you want to 1) check A from B and 2) NOT run B if A is active. One issue with this is you are *already running B* in order to check the status of A.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the REST API to check for the status :

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01
```

learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory